# Load csv files into BIGquery and adding a date column while insert data

Tags: python, pandas, google-bigquery

I am writing a python cloud function to load csv files into BigQuery after adding a new column creation_date . Till now no success. Is there any way to achieve this using cloud function or pandas.
Any help will be appreciated.
I have already gone through other links where csv file is getting generated and kept in GCS after adding date column .My requirement is not to create any extra file.Do you think pandas will be good option.Please suggest.

Thanks
Ritu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's possible to accomplish that with CloudFunction.

What you could do, download the csv file to the Cloud Function docker instance (/tmp directory), load to pandas dataframe and from there you can manipulate the data according to your needs (add/remove column/rows, etc).

Once the data is ready to be loaded into BQ, you can use the method:

```
load_job = client.load_table_from_dataframe(
             dataframe, table_id, job_config=job_config
           )
```

Update:

I see Pandas supports gs:// now loading directly from GCS.

```
df = pd.read_csv('gs://bucket/your_path.csv')
```

Ref: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html

Comment: can we pass in blob file instead of /tmp

Comment: Yes, you can. I just tested it and checked the documentation. I put an example on my response.

Answer (score 0):

You must create the dataset and table in Big Query, along with the types of each column. Then, define a "time created" column in your dataframe, `creation_date` variable:

```
import pandas as pd

creation_date = pd.Timestamp.now() # for each entry in the table
```

Then, save your dataframe into Big Query, `same names of pandas columns`, with specific names of columns and `df`, `your_pandas_dataframe`:

```
from google.cloud import bigquery

client = bigquery.Client()

job_config = bigquery.LoadJobConfig(
    schema=[
        bigquery.SchemaField("DATE", bigquery.enums.SqlTypeNames.DATE), # create each column in Big Query along with types
        bigquery.SchemaField("NAME_COLUMN_2", bigquery.enums.SqlTypeNames.STRING),
        bigquery.SchemaField("NAME_COLUMN_3", bigquery.enums.SqlTypeNames.STRING),
        bigquery.SchemaField("NAME_COLUMN_4", bigquery.enums.SqlTypeNames.INTEGER),
    ],
    write_disposition="WRITE_APPEND",
)

job = client.load_table_from_dataframe(
    your_pandas_dataframe, 'project.dataset.table', job_config=job_config
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can definitely use pandas for this. This is my tested example that works

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime

# df = pd.from_csv('ex.csv')
df = pd.DataFrame({'test': ['one', 'two']})
data = []
for i in range(0, df.shape[0]):
       if i == 0:
              data.append(str(datetime. today()).split(".")[0])
       else:
              data.append("")
df['creation_date'] = data
print(df)
# df.to_csv('temp/save.csv')
```

Comment: i tired your option but i can see creation_date is not getting added to all rows but only to first row