# loading data from csv to bigquery with date fields

Tags: python, pandas, date, google-bigquery, field

Reading csv data with pandas and loading dataframe to BigQuery seems to be very challenging when data contains dates. My BQ table has field defined as DATE, my CSV file contains field `processing_date` with values like these: `2021-01-31`

When I use:

```
df = pd.read_csv(
    file_name, engine="c",
    dtype={'id': 'string', 'processing_date': object}, parse_dates=['processing_date']
)
```

I get BigQuery error:

```
Field processing_date has changed type from DATE to TIMESTAMP
```

When I use:

```
df = pd.read_csv(
    file_name, engine="c",
    dtype={'id': 'string', 'processing_date': 'object'}
)
```

I get BigQuery error:

```
Field processing_date has changed type from DATE to STRING
```

Is it possible to load it as DATE at all? Thanks!

Comment: Check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68655913/load-csv-files-into-bigquery-and-adding-a-date-column-while-insert-data/68656072#68656072

Answer (score 1):

yes it is possible, try this:

```
from google.cloud import bigquery

# Construct a BigQuery client object.
client = bigquery.Client()

# TODO(developer): Set table_id to the ID of the table to create.
table_id = "your-project.your_dataset.your_table_name"
file_path = 'PATH_TO_CSV_FILE_HERE'

job_config = bigquery.LoadJobConfig(
    schema=[
        # all fields definition here:
        bigquery.SchemaField("starting_time", "DATETIME"),
        bigquery.SchemaField("ending_time", "DATETIME"),
        bigquery.SchemaField("price", "STRING")
    ],
    source_format=bigquery.SourceFormat.CSV,
    skip_leading_rows=1,
    autodetect=True,
)

with open(file_path, "rb") as source_file:
    job = client.load_table_from_file(source_file, table_id, job_config=job_config)

job.result()  # Waits for the job to complete.

table = client.get_table(table_id)  # Make an API request.
```

and csv file looks that:

```
starting_time,ending_time,price
2022-04-01T12:13:46,2022-04-01T12:13:46,price
```